# Azure DevOps self-hosted agent is not able to download artifact from Azure Artifacts

Tags: azure-artifacts, azure-devops-server-2020

Azure DevOps Server 2020 with self hosted agents on a different server

I have a build, which is creating an artifact in Azure Artifacts, then a release pipeline is triggered which should download this artifact and do something with it. Previously, the output of a build was on a file share and it work as expected. When I switched to Azure Artifacts - the download artifact task (which is added automatically by Azure DevOps) fails with following:

[image]

All other build tasks work on this server without a problem, and also this release pipeline works as expected on other servers. How I can start to troubleshoot this issue as I don't see any meaningful error message?

Comment: Hi @ldl. I could reproduce the similar issue on my sever. You could refer to the answer and check if the issue is same as yours. Please check if the methods could solve this issue. If no, you could try to set the variable `system.debug = true` in release pipeline. Then you could get more detailed log. And you could share more log with us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your screenshot, I could reproduce the similar issue in Azure Devops Server.

[image]

But in the task, I could see the error message:

> Failed in getBuildApi with error: Error: self signed certificate.

If you have the same issue, you could try the following methods:

1.You could re-config the agent with the `self signed certificate`.

```
.\config.cmd --sslcacert ca.pem  xxxx
```

Here is [a ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/7214) about the detailed steps, you could refer to it.

2.You could check if you have set the firewall. Firewalls could block the download of artifacts

3.You could set the system environment :`NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` and restart the agent services.

Comment: Number 3 was the answer in my case - we do use a certificate created in-house (CA is ours)

Answer (score 1):

We had similar problem with self-hosted agents but there was a minor difference - our agents were deployed in vnet.

If that's the case make sure that in vnet's subnet you have enabled `Microsoft.Storage` service endpoint.

[image]

Hope this will save someone tons of time.